# Loop for in em getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Por que quando uso for in para aplicar uma regra a todos os elementos de uma classe html através do javascript até funciona mas sempre aparece este erro no console?

**TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[i].style is undefined**

```js
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("minha-classe");

for (var i in e) {
  e[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O retorno de [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) é um objeto do tipo [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), não apenas um objeto `NodeList`. Este objeto possui um atributo de somente leitura chamado `length` e métodos chamados `item` e `namedItem` que são incluídos nas iterações quando utilizado o `for`. Para verificar, basta exibir o valor de `i`:

```js
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("minha-classe");

for (let i in e) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
```

O erro é gerado quando o valor `length` é atribuído à variável `i`, pois o código tenta definir o estilo de um elemento `e[length]`, mas este não é um elemento HTML. Para contornar o problema, basta alterar a estrutura de repetição:

```js
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("minha-classe");

for (let i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
  e[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
```

Assim você garante que os valores de `i` serão sempre válidos e percorrerá todos os elementos da lista.

---

### Utilizando o `for ... of`

Utilizando ES6 é possível utilizar o `for ... of` ao invés de `for ... in`. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("minha-classe");

for (let i of e) {
  i.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
<div class="minha-classe">...</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, ajudou bastante. Fazia um tempo que eu tava tentando entender porque isso acontecia.